# How to properly design a class that should contain dual language information

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design, dns, class-design

If my domain object should contain string properties in 2 languages, should I create 2 separate properties or create a new type BiLingualString?

For example in plant classification application, the plant domain object can contain Plant.LatName and Plant.EngName.

The number of bi-lingual properties for the whole domain is not big, about 6-8, I need only to support **two** languages, information should be presented to UI in **both** languages at the same time. (so this is not locallization). The requirements will not change during development.

It may look like an easy question, but this decision will have impact on validation, persistance, object cloning and many other things.

Negative sides I can think of using new dualString type:

- Validation: If i'm going to use DataAnattations, Enterprise Library validation block, Flued validation this will require more work, object graph validation is harder than simple property validation.
- Persistance: iether NH or EF will require more work with complex properties.
- OOP: more complex object initialization, I will have to initialize this new Type in constructor before I can use it.
- Architecture: converting objects for passing them between layers is harder, auto mapping tools will require more hand work.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you won't need to add third language in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you 100% sure that it will always be only Latin and English I would just stick with simplest solution -  2 string properties. It also more flexible in UI then having BiLingualString. And you won't have to deal with Complex types when persisting.

Answer (score 5):

While reading your question I was thinking about `why not localization` all the time but when I read `information should be presented to UI in both languages at the same time.` I think it makes sense to use properties.

In this case I would go for a class with one string for each languages as you have mentioned `BiLingualString`

```
public class Names
{
    public string EngName {get;set;}
    public string LatName {get;set;}
}
```

Then I would use this class in my main Plant Class like this

```
public class Plant: Names
{

}
```

Comment: @Haris: I want to keep my domain objects POCO, why inheritance instead of containment? Plant{public Names Name;}.

Comment: Well, IMHO doesn't make much different in this particular case.. so you can do whatever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: @Haris Hasan what is advantage of having separate class instead of 2 plain string properties?

Comment: @qrow I think this structure will incorporate changes more easily if in future some change in requirement comes like adding more languages or to display only one language at a time(through localization)

Comment: @Haris Hasan I think author clearly pointed out that it will be only 2 languages. And he mentioned Latin, so his domain is probably about medicine (or another field where they use native  + latin language). So again, what is advantage of having class for this if we agree that there will be only 2 languages?

Comment: @qrow: I can think of only 1 advantage of having new Type, in situation when you need to copy object, you will have to write 1 line of code instead of 2.

Comment: @Alex Burtsev compare this really small advantage with disadvantages that you mentioned in question

Comment: @qrow: In terms of defensive programming, uisng 2 properties is not correct, I don't know how this is going to be used by other programmers, and using new complex type (1 property), I show my intention that this data should be used together, this is more intuitive and error prone.

Comment: @Alex Burtsev in what situations this data should be used together? Is it required to enter both eng and lat name when adding new plant to system or only one is enough?

Comment: @qrow: If we are talking about validation than, it depends, some objects should have both properties, some can have none, some may have only one, from the object point of view, it doesn't metter, the object will and should work in any case, object behavior doesn't depend on this data.

Comment: @Alex Burtsev what i'm trying to figure out is if those LatName and EngName is really should go as single thing? For example if you representing circle, it has properties X and Y and radius, i think it's obvious that X and Y should be refactored to Point type. Now take person, it has many properties, FirstName and SecondName among them, but i usually don't create separate type FullName, I just have 2 properties in Person type. So is LatName and EngName is like X and Y or more like FirstName and SecondName?

Comment: @qrow: that's a good question, your refactor x,y to point, because this object can contain operations that work on both X and Y, like Point.Offset(1,1), and because it's a part of domain (geometry) and helps solve domain problems. Now to our biString, does it somehow involved in solving domain problems? I guess no, it's not some program involved in text manipulation, like tranlator. Do I need operations that works on both EngName and LatName? probably not, thought I can imagine such operations, for example Shorten(), MakeFirstCharUpper().

Answer (score 2):

To help decide, I suggest considering how consistent this behavior will be at all layers.  If you expose these as two separate properties on the business object, I would also expect to see it stored as two separate columns in a database record, for example, rather than two translations for the same property stored in a separate table.  It does seem odd to store translations this way, but your justifications sound reasonable, and 6 properties is not un-managable.  But be sure that you don't intend to add more languages in the future.

If you expect this system to by somewhat dynamic in that you may need to add another language at some point, it would seem to make more sense to me to implement this differently so that you don't have to alter the schema when a new language needs to be supported.

I guess the thing to balance is this: consider the likelihood of having to adjust the languages or properties to accommodate a new language against the advantage (simplicity) you gain by exposing these directly as separate properties rather than having to load translations as a separate level.